# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

Tags: iis, iis-7

IN VS 2008 i can run .svc but on production IIS 7 i can't. I get this error. i am using x64 win.

I run

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.5.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319).
.........................
```

and

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
The error indicates that IIS is not installed on the machine. Please install IIS
Finished installing ASP.NET (2.0.50727).
```

but it is the same. I run VS 2008. Application pool :NET framweork is 2.0. And i enable 32 bit application

```
    Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
Detailed Error Information
Module  StaticFileModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070032
Requested URL   http://192.168.2.4:80/Service.svc
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebServices\Service.svc
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
Most likely causes:

    The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.

Things you can try:

    If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.
```

EDIT:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
        <section name="nhibernateSettings" type="ProjectBase.Data.NHibernateSessionMgmt.OpenSessionInViewSection, ProjectBase.Data" />
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="NHibernateConfigPath" value="D:\PROJEKTI\WebServices\DotNet\WebServices\WebServices\NHibernate.config" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=WebServices;Data Source=.\SQL2008" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <nhibernateSettings>
        <!-- List every session factory that will be needed; transaction management and closing sessions 
          will be managed with the open-session-in-view module -->
        <sessionFactories>
            <clearFactories />
            <sessionFactory name="WebCrawlerFactory" factoryConfigPath="D:\PROJEKTI\WebServices\DotNet\WebServices\WebServices\NHibernate.config" isTransactional="true" />
        </sessionFactories>
    </nhibernateSettings>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="LogAllToFile" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="WebCrawler.log" />
            <appendToFile value="false" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5l - %m%n%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <priority value="ALL" />
            <!-- ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF-->
            <appender-ref ref="LogAllToFile" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
            </webServices>
            <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WebServices.Service" behaviorConfiguration="WebServices.ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebServices.IService">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WebServices.ServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had receievd a similar error:

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

I tried the same code on several machines. Through some R & D, I finally found that the cause for this can be that WCF mapping are not registered with IIS.

To solve the above error:

1. Navigate to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows
   Communication Foundation" at the Visual Studio command prompt
2. Execute `servicemodelreg -i` to install the mappings manually

Comment: Technically 
ServiceModelReg.exe -1  and thank you.

Answer (score 103):

[image]Issue was solved by enabling the windows communication foundation -> HttpActivation on windows features.

Comment: Had to do both 3.5 and 4.5 Activation for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: FINALLY! After reinstalling things a billion times, running all reg solutions (aspnet_regiis and servicemodelreg) ... finally found the problem. In Windows 8, it's in Windows Features -> .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services -> WCF Services -> HTTP Activation Thanks a lot!

Comment: for  4 and 4.5 in windows 8.1 only with Activation.. Worked for me as well. thanks.

Comment: +1 and I wish I could vote for this billion of times. Thanks, Thanks. you saved my day, after spending four hours trying solving this. Thanks again.

Comment: As explains in http://gasparnagy.com/2014/01/enable-net-4-0-wcf-hosing-in-iis-8/ this should be the answer. Thanks

Comment: also possible in PowerShell: Add-WindowsFeature 'NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45' (for getting names for other features use Get-WindowsFeature)

Answer (score 4):

For Win7 machines, the same setting can be made under Conrol Panel-->Programs and Features-->Turn Windows features on or off

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

Either you have 2 nodes for `<scriptResourceHandler>` in your web.config, or your .svc file has its own web.config and there's another web.config in the same IIS application that defines `<scriptResourceHandler>`. If this is supposed to be a self-contained site that's nested under another ASP.NET site, you would need to create it as an application through the IIS admin tool, but without knowing how your site/applications are structured, I can't offer much more help.

Comment: i do not have 2 scriptResourceHandler and also not 2 web.config

Answer (score 1):

I struggled the whole day with this issue. Had all the config stuff right and relevant features installed on server. Found out my app was deployed in an app pool which used the .net clr runtime: Unmanaged code. Changed it to 4.0 and boom works!

Answer (score 0):

WCF mapping are not registered with IIS.

Navigate to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation` and execute `servicemodelreg -i` to install them manually

Comment: Duplicate answer of the accepted answer, but with less useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Have just been battling with a BizTalk WCF service deployed on Windows Server 2012 IIS. And after testing Everything else, something else shot to mind, Application pools. IF the application pool is set to Classic mode you need to have your httpHandlers under Control, they need to be defined for all file types you intend to use. If you run the application in Integrated mode, IIS will take care of this just fine. Might be good for someone who finds themselves here after googling. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you run 32 bit apps in .net v2.0 you should set true `Enable 32-bit Application` to `True` under General section

Answer (score -1):

I had to manually add handler mappings for svc NET 4.0. Somehow they have dissapeared from list of IIS mappings.

I got the idea  [HERE](https://support.arvixe.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/152/11/how-to-fix-wcf-svc-file-gives-a-404-error).