# Configured the WCF service on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

I have windows server 2012 and sharepoint 2013 installed. Now i wanted to configured my wcf service on the server.

After Creating the new app pool & site its shows me the error as below
**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Also i have found the solution on the link below
[HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083533/http-error-404-17-not-found)

where suggested to run the command "servicemodelreg -i". I have did the same and my service started working. But the sharepoint services are stopped working showing the below error

**Exception message:** Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Please help me out to the resolve this problem.....

Thanks is advance

Comment: If you need help with your configuration, perhaps you should post it?