# Clasic ASP webapp get HTTP Error 404.17 in new server

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a big problem mounting a very old webapp. The app is developed in ASP (not ASP.Net), and in the new server (Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10) it is giving me the 404.17 error.

I have installed all the add-ons for the IIS.

I have created the mapping handler correctly (trying to add via IIS too):

```
  <handlers>
            <add name="ASP Clasic" path="*.asp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="bitness64" />
  </handlers>
```

The appPool is in 32 bits, Managed Pipeline in classic...

In the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions Active Server Pages are allowed.

But any application wants to work in classic asp... (I try with a simple page in asp that give my the system hour and fail too, with this I rule out application failures and make sure that it is a matter of IIS configuration)

Does anyone have any ideas that can guide me?

Comment: Not sure that's enough to go on.

Comment: It's fantastic that you isolated the error number (this is far more effort than most posts here) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/error-message-you-visit-web-site. Maybe you should change `bitness64` to `bitness32` in your handler mapping?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid But that is the 64 Bit  location on 64 Bit machines, if it was the bitness that was the problem the 32 Bit location would be `%windir%\SysWOW64\inetsrv\asp.dll`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083533/http-error-404-17-not-found)

Comment: Good point about the 32 bit location. I missed that bit. In summary, everything has to be the same bitness. The OP mentions "The appPool is in 32 bits". So I agree we need `scriptProcessor=%windir%\SysWOW64\inetsrv\asp.dll` as well as `preCondition="bitness32"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to solve the problem:

1. Go to IIS > Sites > example.com > Handler Mapping > Add Script Map.
2. Enter the following information:

   RequestPath: *.asp

   Executable: %windir%\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll

   Name: ASPClassic

   Request Restrictions: File

   Verbs: GET,HEAD,POST

   Access: Script